# Data Type Mismatch in SQL when comparing a field against another field that has a null value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've been given a data set that contains 7 columns Reject1, Reject2,... etc. Each reject code that is in the column has a priority, 1 being highest priority and 9999 being the lowest. Unfortunately, the data is not normalized (I know shoot me in the face) and I have been tasked with finding the highest priority reject code from seven columns in one record and then returning that reject code.

What I've been able to do is left join the data to a table that has the hierarchy for the reject codes i.e. Reject code 79 = 1 Priority. So I now have 7 Reject Code columns along with 7 Priority columns to correspond.

My initial idea was to write a bunch of update queries that would update a `TopPriority` column after comparing two priority columns.

```
UPDATE tblPriority 
SET tblPriority.HighestPriority = tblPriority.Priority1
```

So the above code works fine. The issue is with the second bit of SQL:

```
UPDATE tblPriority 
SET tblPriority.HighestPriority = tblPriority.Priority2  
WHERE tblPriority.HighestPriority > tblPriority.Priority2
```

The above code gives me a data type mismatch and I'm assuming it is because the Priority2 column is null? If so how does on solve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: just filter the nulls `WHERE tblPriority.Priority2 IS NOT NULL...` I'm not sure the equivalent of access maybe its !=Null or <> Null

Comment: It is `IS NOT NULL` in Access as well

Comment: typically in an update statement you cannot use a table qualifier. So `SET tblPriority.HighestPriority` should be `SET HighestPriority`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can normalize the data pretty easily it seems

```
Select thingBeingRejected, Reject1 as RejectCode, 'Reject1' as SourceColumn
union all Select thingBeingRejected, Reject2 as RejectCode, 'Reject2' as SourceColumn
union all Select thingBeingRejected, Reject3 as RejectCode, 'Reject3' as SourceColumn
union all Select thingBeingRejected, Reject4 as RejectCode, 'Reject4' as SourceColumn
union all Select thingBeingRejected, Reject5 as RejectCode, 'Reject5' as SourceColumn
union all Select thingBeingRejected, Reject6 as RejectCode, 'Reject6' as SourceColumn
union all Select thingBeingRejected, Reject7 as RejectCode, 'Reject7' as SourceColumn
```

Then find the max like normal

```
Select max(p.priority), nrc.thingBeingRejected
from NormalizedRejectCodes nrc
inner join Priorities p on p.RejectCode = nrc.RejectCode
group by nrc.thingBeingRejected
```